# Embedded font in Metro specially for Tile Update

Tags: c#, fonts, windows-8, microsoft-metro

- How can I use an embedded font in Metro UI app?
- Is it possible to use one for Tile Update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To embed font in your Windows Store app, add the font to your project as "Content", and in your XAML simply write something like:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="/Fonts/MyFont.otf#Cool Font"/>
```

Assuming your font name is "Cool Font", the file name is "MyFont.otf", and you placed in "Fonts" folder

Answer (score 0):

Regarding how to use an embedded font, first take a look at [About font embedding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms530303(v=vs.85).aspx).  Some of the classes that you might use are [CreateFontFace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368196(v=vs.85).aspx) or [CreateFontFileReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368197(v=vs.85).aspx).

No, there is not a way to change the font on your tile during a tile update (unless of course the font is part of your logo/image that you are sending to the tile).  For reference, here is the [tile schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212859.aspx) for sending live updates to your tile, which doesn't have a way to change the font.

Comment: This didn't answer he first part of the question. The links to `CreateFontFace` and `CreateFontFileReference` are for C++ while the question is about C#. Also, the link to "About font embedding" isn't valid any more.